Trying to find a dragon book I read as a kid
What is this dragon book I read as a kid?
The main character is the daughter of the lord/noble thingy, dad dies, brother expects to inherit but SHE has been given the inheritance ring (silver, dragon, comes to life and hisses when they try take it off her).
The dragon industry is rather like the old horse industry, complete with stables, battle dragons, training dragons, dragons having to be put down if they break a wing because they can't survive, etc. etc., HOWEVER SHE CAN SPEAK TO THEM, telepathically kinda? Anyway she saves a dragon from being put down, a war dragon, "deadly and dangerous" he was called? He was "gorse yellow and bright red". She and this dragon bond (NOT romance).
Her brother is BAD at dragons, he normally rides hippogriffs instead, though still sucks at that unless it's a well behaved mount, but he STILL wants to inherit the dragon empire/estate/business. Witch makes HER a problem for him, SOOO... he murders her dragon and has her banished. She escapes, can't remember how. There's also something about a prison mine maybe.
But I DO remember that:
A) She manages to save one scale of her beloved dragon WHICH THEN MERGES INTO HER PALM, LIKE BECOMES PART OF HER SKIN.
B) Before her dad died her gave her the ring and said he thought she was some legendary dragon shifter figure (dragon lord? dragon kin?) because she can talk to dragons. She responds with "but I can't turn into a dragon so I can't be" and he's basically "yeah but it's about more than that, plus you're young you can't yet, but I still think it's you and I want you to inherit, have the ring".
C) Once she escapes she meets up with a few loyal staff/generals and they have a suprise, her dragon had fathered a litter before he died. One of them is the chubby runt of the litter but looks JUST like his father, same markings, so she chooses and is raising him.
But the first book ends with her on a dragon (her fathers old dragon that she rescued?) and they are both plummeting out of the sky about to die and her dragon powers start waking up and they get surrounded by a net of protective flame. The book ends before they hit the ground, a cliffhanger.
I read it in one go in a Scottish library as a kid, sometime in or before 2009. Put the book back on the shelf completely, forgot the title and could never find it or the rest of the series.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall the cover art?

This appears to be Flight to Dragon Isle (2011) by Lucinda Hare, sequel to The Dragon Whisperer (2009).
The protagonist, Quenelda, can hear the thoughts of dragons, and is given her own dragon, Two Gulps and You're Gone, by her father.  He also give her his ring, and her step-brother Darcy is extremely jealous of both.
The bit about the dragon scale merging into Quenelda's palm:

There, on the palm of her hand, was a gorse-yellow scale. It was soft, but rapidly hardening like a newly laid egg. Even as she looked, it seemed to sink into her skin so that she could see the lines on her palm through it. But when she touched it with a finger, her palm too was as hard as a scale.


And did she hit the ground and die?

The time is wrong for Flight to Dragon Isle (OP says at or before 2009), but I could see the OP having an off-by-2 error on the year, since this otherwise seems a perfect match. Maybe they read the first book in '09, then the second in '11, and remembered stuff from the second book as having happened in the first book, filing the memories with the '09 reading? I've done that before (when the third book in the Founders Trilogy came out, I remembered reading only the first book, but on reading the second, I realized I'd read it before and misremembered it as the second half of the first book).

@DavidW OMG YES THATS THE EXACT BOOK THANK YOU!!! yeah, absolutely two gulps and your gone no idea how I fegot that!!!

And yeah @ShadowRanger I Absolutely just got the year muddled up, I was kinda hazy on that anyway, and can absolutely see me read both books in one sitting and not realising later
